# Uploading Image

Tags: php, mysql, gallery

I have done uploading image. Code is working perfect. I want to insert my session id while saving images into database. How can I save session id in insert query.view file for showing images in a gallery. I want to show them as user.

That is why I need to save the user id to retrieve specific images for specific user. Now it is fetching all images from database. I want to store user id to track down specific images. Here I have started my session.  This is my session id.

```
   <?php
             session_start();   //what can be done to save this id.I need save this staffid to save in the database.What is the process

            if(!$this->session->userdata('staffid')){             redirect("login/checkLogin");
}
            ?>

   <?php
```

I want to save this id into database for fetching specific images. I need to save that id as category id in my database so that I don't have to make another table for making any galleries just upload them with a name that can be use as gallery name.

```
   if (isset($_POST["sub1"]) || isset($_POST["sub2"])) {
          // include resized library
          require_once('./php-image-magician/php_image_magician.php'); //library for showing images in thumbnail.This library is helping for showing images as gallery. 
          $msg = "";
          $valid_image_check = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/bmp");
          if (count($_FILES["user_files"]) > 0) {
            $folderName = "uploads/";

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_images(image_name) VALUES (:img)";  //have insert my session id here.What is the procedure to insert session id in sql insert query.
            $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["user_files"]["name"]); $i++) { //Here is the loop for saving multiple images in database.

              if ($_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] <> "") {

                $image_mime = strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i])));
                // if valid image type then upload
                if (in_array($image_mime, $valid_image_check)) {

                  $ext = explode("/", strtolower($image_mime));
                  $ext = strtolower(end($ext));
                  $filename = rand(10000, 990000) . '_' . time() . '.' . $ext;
                  $filepath = $folderName . $filename;
 //this will save the folder name and file path in database.There is no problem saving them.Working successfully.

                  if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $filepath)) {
                    $emsg .= "Failed to upload <strong>" . $_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] . "</strong>. <br>";
                    $counter++;
                  } else {
                    $smsg .= "<strong>" . $_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] . "</strong> uploaded successfully. <br>";

                    $magicianObj = new imageLib($filepath);
                    $magicianObj->resizeImage(100, 100);
                    $magicianObj->saveImage($folderName . 'thumb/' . $filename, 100);

                    /*             * ****** insert into database starts ******** */
                    try {
                      $stmt->bindValue(":img", $filename); //i have to insert my session id in here.
                      $stmt->execute();
                      $result = $stmt->rowCount();
                      if ($result > 0) {
                        // file uplaoded successfully.
                      } else {
                        // failed to insert into database.
                      }
                    } catch (Exception $ex) {
                      $emsg .= "<strong>" . $ex->getMessage() . "</strong>. <br>";
                    }
                    /*             * ****** insert into database ends ******** */
                  }
                } else {
                  $emsg .= "<strong>" . $_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] . "</strong> not a valid image. <br>";  
//After checking file type if anything goes wrong it will show this message.File type is given.
                }
              }
            }


            $msg .= (strlen($smsg) > 0) ? successMessage($smsg) : "";
            $msg .= (strlen($emsg) > 0) ? errorMessage($emsg) : "";
          } else {
            $msg = errorMessage("You must upload atleast one file");//validation for uploading files.
          }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You first need to write clean and easy-to-read code

Answer (score 1):

Ok first thing is you need to understand sessions [W3Schools Description](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

If I understand you correctly:

- you would like to save a link of the current user to a Image (which is saved in your session) and then
- pull that users saved images at later stage.

Is this correct?

Asuming that "staffid" is unique:

1. create a column on the image table:

   ALTER TABLE  `tbl_images` ADD  `staffid` INT NOT NULL
2. then change your insert statement to

   $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_images (image_name, staffid) VALUES (:img, :staffid)";
3. and

   $stmt->bindValue(":img", $filename);
    $stmt->bindValue(":staffid", $this->session->userdata('staffid'));
4. Then when select only need to pass in current users id add a where clause and prepare the query accordingly.This will return all images saved by that user:

   WHERE staffid=:staffid;